# Preg_match alphanumeric -_' ", and white space

Tags: php, regex

Anyone have a regex to allow alphanumerics and -_",' as well as white spaces?

Comment: By "allow" do you mean an expression that matches what you said, or an expression which matches everything other than what you said?

Comment: I mean anything that doesn't match will cause an exception. Basically I just want plain text and -_",' to go thru and block anything else licke <> [] tags that sort of stuff

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9-_",'\s]+$/
```

Comment: Nope, I am using the following

   $pattern ="/^[A-Za-z0-9-_",'\s]+$/";
   if ($string && preg_match($pattern, $string))

PHP kicks out - syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: try escaping the single and double quotes *inside* the regex: `/^[A-Za-z0-9-_\",\'\s]+$/`

Comment: Is the `-` between the `9` and `_` intended to match a literal `-`? If so, putting it at the beginning or end of the class might make the expression more suitable to other languages.

Comment: @jason: You need to escape it properly: `"/^[A-Za-z0-9-_\",'\\s]+\$/"`.

Comment: @Tim: What language does not recognize a literal `-` if it’s not at the start or the end of a character class?

Comment: @Gumbo, true, probably in all PCRE flavours, you needn't escape the hyphen if it's preceded by a character range or shorthand character class. However, IMO it's (1) easier to understand when placed at the start or end of the character class and (2) if the requirements change and the `0-9` part is removed, bugs can creep in the regex if all of a sudden the `-` gets treated as a range operator.

Answer (score 0):

I have read quite a lot on the \s flag within regex, I see it handed out like candy all over stackoverflow however it would appear that the \s flag matches all on metacharacters and also skips line breaks.

This will allow ignoring filtered user input for all kinds of characters you do not want in your software, website or database.

The \s flag also skips new line breaks leaving filtered code vulnerable to inclusion so use this method at your own risk otherwise happy hacking lol...

You may consider something like this: `/[^\p{Xan}]++$/D`

- `\p{Xan}` matches all unicode alphabet letters and numbers, if this
  doesn't allow all alphabet white space then I am unsure how to safly
  match these for a filter.
- `++` makes use of the possessive quantifier that can help optimize
  the match
- `$/D` causes the regex to terminate at the end of the string and not 
  skip over any characters before a line break

\s flag:

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>       If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are
>   excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A
>   negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,
>   independent of the setting of this modifier.

Metacharacters:

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter

> A metacharacter is a character that has a special meaning (instead of
>   a literal meaning) to a computer program, such as a shell interpreter
>   or a regular expression engine.
>
> In regular expressions, there are 11 metacharacters that must always
>   be preceded by a backslash, \, to be used inside of the expression:
>
> The opening square bracket [, the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar
>   sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the
>   question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening
>   round bracket ( and the closing round bracket ).[1]
>
> If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex,
>   you need to escape them with a backslash. If you want to match 1+1=2,
>   the correct regex is 1+1=2. Otherwise, the plus sign will have a
>   special meaning.